# How did Hideki Matsui's "one day" signing affect the Yankees' 40-man roster?

Tags: baseball

[Hideki Matsui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hideki_Matsui), a Japanese player, played for a Japanese baseball team, then the New York Yankees for several years, then several more U.S. teams. On July 28, 2013, he signed a final one day contract with the Yankees, in order to retire as a Yankee.

How, if at all, did that affect the Yankees' 40 man roster? 1) Did they pick a day when they had only 39 men because of injuries or other reasons, making Matsui the 40th for one day? 2) Is there a "window" of say, 24 hours whereby the Yankees could temporarily have 41 men, as long as Matsui leaves within that window? 3) Or did the Yankees actually have to make a roster move to accommodate Matsui.

Comment: Or potentially 4) the whole "one day contract" thing is a nice bit of marketing, but actually not a player contract at all so has no bearing on the roster.

Comment: Other than for Rule 5 draft picks, there is no requirement to place a signed player on any particular roster, including the 40-man roster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/07/31/sports/the-one-day-contract-a-last-hurrah-for-athletes.html?_r=0) explains the "one-day minor league contract"<sub>([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hideki_Matsui))</sub> Matsui signed, for a Yankees affiliate. This did not affect the Yankees' 40-man roster<sub>([2](http://www.foxsports.com/mlb/just-a-bit-outside/story/the-full-meaning-of-signing-a-minor-league-deal-021315))</sub>.

> In baseball, the one-day contract is typically a minor league deal.
>   The Yankees, for example, would have needed to clear a spot on their
>   40-man roster to actually sign Matsui this week, so there was a bit of
>   stagecraft at work. An announcement that Matsui was retiring as a
>   member of the Trenton Thunder would have carried considerably less
>   heft, though it probably would have been more accurate